# Defining an object with a dynamic key in node js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object-object-mapping

I need to do this :

```
let obj = {}
obj.obj1 =  {'obj11':5}
console.log(obj.obj1.obj11)

//5
```

but I need to define the last key of the last object dynamically for example, something like this:

```
let obj = {}
key = 'obj11'
obj.obj1 =  { key :5}
console.log(obj.obj1.obj11)
// undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

To define  computed properties in javascript objects use `[]`.

Try the following:

```js
let obj = {}
key = 'obj11'
obj.obj1 =  { [key] :5}
console.log(obj.obj1.obj11)
```

For reference : [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: @CarlosFelipe Please mark as accepted if the answer helped you :-)

Comment: No, mark this answer as excepted *if* this is the best answer available.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
obj.obj1[key] = 5;

console.log(obj.obj1.obj11);
```

The object notation syntax does not support variables as keys directly, but java-script dictionaries do.

To evaluate the variable in the object notation syntax, use a bracket like so

```
obj.obj1 = {[key]: 5};

console.log(obj.obj1.obj11);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use bracket notation for this like

```js
let obj = {}
key = 'obj11'
obj.obj1 =  { [key] :5}
console.log(obj.obj1.obj11)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this:

```
console.log(obj.obj1[key]);
```

Every object in JavaScript is basically a dictionary so you can access it via the dictionary syntax.